# IdentityServer 4 as a Console Application

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4

I'm trying to run IdentityServer4 as console application. But I'm unsure if I'm doing right. I created *Console Application (.NET Core)* instead of *ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)*.

My setup of `WebHostBuilder` is pretty straightforward:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Also the *Startup* class is very tiny:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
                .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();
        app.UseIdentityServer();
    }
}
```

I'm just concerned if I'm missing some pieces which could lead to problems later. Am I on the right way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the steps to create *Identity Server v4* executable using *.NET Core version 1.1*.

Create project with *Console Application (.NET Core)*. In the `Main`method implement following code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Title = "IdentityServer";

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

In the `Startup` class implement following code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddTestUsers(Config.GetUsers());
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
    }
}
```

To generate executable, you *must not have* a `"type": "platform"` in your *project.json*. For example my *project.json* looks like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "IdentityServer4": "1.1.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
    }
  },

  "runtimes": {
    "win7-x64": {},
    "win8-x64": {},
    "win10-x64": {}
  }
}
```

Than you can generate executable with *dotnet publish* command like below.

`dotnet publish -c release -r win7-x64`
`dotnet publish -c release -r win8-x64`
`dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x64`

*Disclaimer: This is minimal running version, maybe you will need extended configuration, depends on what you need.*

Answer (score 1):

Every .NET Core application is a console application. So it does not make a difference which template you are using.

But I think in your main - you are missing a call to `UseContentRoot`.

Comment: Yes that's true, my point is to run _IdentityServer_ as _*.exe_. Can I do this with _ASP.Net Core_ template? Oh and thank you for the hint with `UseContentRoot`. What is the implication of this settings?

Comment: When you target the full framework you will get an exe - netcore will always produce a dll that you can run with dotnet run.

Answer (score 0):

You could publish a self-contained application as described in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/10/11/net-core-how-to-publish-a-self-contained-application-exe/

Comment: This sample isn't valid for .NET Core 1.1